# itunes showing as an update in mac appstore even though updated

Tags: macos, mac, mac-app-store, osx-yosemite

So my problem is that I have updated iTunes to the latest version using the mac app store on os x 10.10 but it still keeps showing that it needs updating even though it is on the latest version!! Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks